# React - know if a component is deeply children of another

Tags: reactjs

I have an array with reference of multiple components (`this` of ES6 Class syntax). My tree is like this:

[image: tree]

I must force render C2-C3-C4. If i render C2, it's useless re-render C4 because the render of parent refresh the children. How i can understand if C2 is children of C4? The sub-level can be more then one obviously.

I'm trying to use context but i can't find the right way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have to force render the child components? In almost all cases, that's not a good idea.

Comment: Use `shouldComponentUpdate`. This way, any parent that doesn't need an update won't update its children. However, I feel like you should have a very, very good reason to be keeping reference to components and updating them manually. This is an imperative approach in a library that is meant to be 100% declarative. Perhaps adding details as to why you need to do this would help us help you find a better way

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `shouldComponentUpdate` ([docs for shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) and [optimizing performance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html)) with a mix of `context`.

You can use context in LifeCycle methods, they are the third parameter:

```
shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
   // Logic here.
   return true;
}
```

PS: I agree with Abhishek, that's not a good idea!

Comment: Thanks to all for replys! I'm trying to create a simpler version of Redux, i use a function to connect components to global store. I save the component reference that are connected to slices of store. When the store change, i will loop to all reference, and update only the components that are connected with the modified slices. But i want force render only the first component and not the children that are connected to the same slices of store, to avoid re-render. I read that i can't change the context (is anti-pattern, and the API is broken).